# Good books for WCF based SOA, Distributed and Server Side Programming?

Tags: .net, wcf, soa, distributed

I am basically a .NET GUI programmer and have worked on a lot of WPF, Winforms and also have used WCF. I joined a new job in a bank and we are currently writing a new software to replace existing trading apps. This involves lot of work based on WCF services and we need to use/implement a lot of SOA related concepts like message broker, pub-sub patterns, message bus etc. So, basically means a lot of server side and distributed programming in my way ahead ! We now use simple WCF services that does our job for our service layer but aiming to make this more scalable, robust, secure and reliable.

I have a basic WCF book but wondering if there is a more specialized SOA, Distributed Architecture based book (based on .NET, WCF or may be not) that can quickly help me to get through the curve of server side programming. Possibly that talks about CEP, EDA etc..

Many Thanks,
Mani

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF Book Recommendation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386801/wcf-book-recommendation)

Comment: and another http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939302/which-book-for-soa-with-net

Comment: I was wondering if these WCF based books cover CEP, EDA, CQRS related topics. But yes, those are useful links.

Comment: CEP, EDA, etc. are more about big SOA. WCF is API to build service. These terms are related to whole infrastructure and usually provided out-of-the box by ESBs etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Professional WCF 4: Windows Communication Foundation with .NET 4.
Pablo Cibraro; Kurt Claeys; Fabio Cozzolino; Johann Grabner

WCF 4.0 Multi-tier Services Development with LINQ to Entities.
Mike Liu

SOA Modeling Patterns for Service-Oriented Discovery and Analysis.
Michael Bell

Pro WCF: Practical Microsoft SOA Implementation.
Chris Peiris; Dennis Mulder

Thanks,
Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

i highly recommend the following books by Lowy and Erl:

- Juval Lowy, *Programming WCF Services*, 3rd Edition for .net 4
- Thomas Erl, *SOA Design Patterns*
- Thomas Erl, *SOA Principles of Service Design*

Lowy has a few WCF articles on the MSDN Mag site